# Is dry or drying solder paste effective on a circuit board

Tags: pcb, solder-paste

My circuit board has some 80 components.  I'm in prototype stage, that is: stenciling with solder paste, placing parts and hot plate soldering. **I see that by the time I get to placing the 80th part, the previously stenciled solder paste appears less fluid (dryer) and it shrinks a little.** Regardless of the state of drying, the components appear to sit nicely in the tiny bath of solder paste.  It takes a good hour to place the components although I can certainly improve the procedure in future builds if need be.

I use RL403 63/37 having a viscosity of 160-230 Pa.s paste that seems to work very well under immediate apply/heat process.

The question is then: Is this drying out of solder paste business over a period of about an hour, actually a problem or can I ignore it.

Comment: Never encountered this problem. I use LOCTITE  GC 10 SAC305T4 885V 52K myself. Can easily take 2/3 hours until reflow.

Comment: Thx .. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An hour should be fine. However you do need to be careful with air movement which will accelerate the drying out. The dryer it gets the more likely you’ll end up with micro bb’s or parts tombstoning instead of a nice solder job.

I try to plan my jobs so I don’t have them open more than a couple hours, and if I have to leave I’ll cover them with plastic to slow down the dry out.

A hot air gun tends to be more forgiving of dry paste than a hot plate or oven likely because it brings the remaining flux to temp faster. If the remaining flux evaporates before it is hot enough to do it’s work, that is where the problem is.

Comment: I just tried again.  This time I printed a "floorplan" and carefully placed each part on the paper first then did a master manual "pick-and-place" prior to soldering.  The protocol works much faster than opening each paper strip parts holder as I go.  Still took an hour but no longer and drying was OK.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: https://www.compuphase.com/visualplace/visualplace_en.htm I think it's free now, it works reasonably well. If you sequence the parts and tape them on a piece of cardboard it works well enough

Comment: Nice ... thanks.  Everything is hard with 0402 parts.  I try to stay bigger now too!

Comment: Hmm. After a around of hand placed 0201 I decided to stick with 0402 :) Fined tipped wiha like these https://www.wihatools.com/products/esd-safe-tweezers-4b-sa seem to work better than straight ones as the parts slide off better. Use a piece of paper to flick resistors to the right side.

Comment: You are a brave soul to even attempt 0201.  I also learned that good quality tweezers are imperative.  Another trick I learned is to mix the solder paste with flux when soldering with hot air.  Works very well for me when working with a magnifying glass.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you ever buy a stereo microscope you'll never be sorry, you can solder underneath it.

Comment: You may push me over the edge! :)  I need something and I'm looking at the options as gift to my strained eyes. I also posted a question on this. The guy at "Northfix" says that he learned quickly to use a camera instead of microscope and prefers it [His comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfkXitg5R4I) and I like the lower price.

Comment: FYI .. in an effort to save money I tried one of these illuminated lamps with a big magnifying lens.  Well .. Its OK for basic soldering and parts placement but fails at inspection.  Finally I returned it.

Comment: It took me a little use to become comfortable with the stereo scope, but it gives depth perception in a way that 2d can't match. For example I can see bridges behind MCU pins that otherwise are hard to perceive.